# Opening ECW files in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, ecw, windows-10

QGIS 2.14.1 opened .ECW files simply via the open raster menu, without any problems. In 2.14.3, the entire ERDAS Compressed Wavelets option has disappeared from the file type drop down, and QGIS returns an error if opening an .ECW is attempted.

How do I open a .ECW file now, in 2.14.3? Have the capabilities been removed or do I need to follow a new technique?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out when using the OSGEO4W installer, the ECW package is not automatically installed with the QGIS desktop software. It can be found separately under the Lib menu.

I am new to using the OSGEO4W installer and this was not obvious to me.

Comment: With the standalone Windows installer, you would have got it by default.

Answer (score 4):

You need to download QGIS 2.14.3 from OSGEO4W in order to be able to open ECW file format. The [QGIS help](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/faq/index.html) stated that clearly. Also, here is a good source on [ADDING ECW SUPPORT IN QGIS](https://faunaliagis.wordpress.com/2013/08/15/adding-ecw-support-in-qgis/). The help provides good information on how to open ECW file format using different operating system.

Comment: Thanks mate. I read the QGIS help when I initially identified the issue, and thought there was something wrong as it says ECW support is automatically included for Windows. I now understand using the OSGEO4W installer you must select and install ECW capabilities separately.