# Is it possible to open .ECW files with QGIS 3.2?

Tags: qgis, ecw

Is it possible to open .ECW files with QGIS 3.2?

I have read [Opening ECW files in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200025/opening-ecw-files-in-qgis), but that applies to QGIS 2.14.3.

Is it possible in QGIS 3.2 without downloading anything as we cannot install anything at work or access the program files?

Comment: It depends on your operating system, which you have not mentioned (yet).

Answer (score 3):

You can open ECW files with QGIS 3.2 . If you are not sure, you could install QGIS 3.2 in a different folder and test it out.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes. ECW is supported out of box for all Windows installs.

Answer (score 1):

You might double-check your QGIS install via the setup routine.[image]

If the ecw lib wasn't installed, you can install it there.
[image]

Then restart QGIS.