# ECW file solution doesn't work in QGIS in the latest ubuntu

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, dem, ubuntu, ecw

In Ubuntu 18.4 I enrolled in a QGIS course in that course .dem file shows but .ecw can not show so what can be the solution can anybody tell me. QGIS version is 3.10.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/200025/opening-ecw-files-in-qgis

Comment: These solution doesn't work so can you give me any details and i am a new user in ubuntu and also in qgis so faces these problem.

Comment: Did you try the linked link in that answer for Ubuntu ~ https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27247/installing-ecw-for-qgis-in-ubuntu-12-04/27398#27398

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing ECW for QGIS in Ubuntu 12.04?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27247/installing-ecw-for-qgis-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 5):

While ecw is supported by default with the QGIS Windows installers, you have to add it manually on ubuntu due to license problems.

You have to compile GDAL yourself with ECW support, using exactly the same GDAL version as your non-ECW build of QGIS has. Otherwise you would need to recompile QGIS too.

See this topic for a start:

[Can't install support for ECW in QGIS 3.6 / 3.4 on Ubuntu 18.04](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313294/cant-install-support-for-ecw-in-qgis-3-6-3-4-on-ubuntu-18-04)